# Error when uploading an File/Image in my Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I've copied the entire code for uploading files in a Symfony2 project, which stores all the data in `web/uploads` folder. The code is from [here](https://gist.github.com/beberlei/978346).

This is working fine in localhost, but in the remote server it is throwing an error:

```
Could not create target directory to move temporary file into.
   500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException
```

[image]

Please address this issue ...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the line 40 of the image shows, the error occurred when the code tried to create a folder, you must see in your server permissions if you can create new folders.

Comment: Yeah, it's a permission problem, you'll need to chmod that bad boy!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your upload directory path is wrong. It says you're trying to create: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads"

You shoud first fetch param "kernel.root_dir" from the container, and then create path to uploads dir. Like this:

```
$kernelRootDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');
$uploadDirPath = $kernelRootDir . '/../web/uploads';
```

My advice would be to manually create that folder, and set it's permissions to 775. If it's imperative that PHP creates the upload dir, make sure that Apache user has write privileges on /web directory

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply, but even its not working.. I've tried with all possible ways from your answer.

Comment: What is the direcoty path that you're trying to create? Can you create it by hand and just move files there?

Comment: manually means,
previously it was ` protected static $uploadDirectory = '%kernel.root_dir%/../uploads';` in `Document.php`

I've tried giving `$uploadDirecctory = '/uploads'` and concatinated in all methods where this $uploadDirectory variable is called with `$kernelRootDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');`  as `$uploadDirectory.self::$uploadDirectory`

Comment: I've tried giving 

`$uploadDirecctory = '/uploads'` 

and concatinated in all methods where this      `$uploadDirectory`        variable is called with           `$kernelRootDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');`        as           `$uploadDirectory.self::$uploadDirectory`       and even tried without using this    `$kernelrootDir`        manually giving  `$uploadDirectory = ' myprjectname/web/uploads'`